# How to go from one tab to another tab in AvalonDock when a button or key is pressed?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, avalondock

I created a view from SampleDockWindowView and I like to go to the other view created window when a button is pressed.

I've already tried Application.Current.Windows. This array is just empty.

```
window2 win2= new window2();
        win2.Show();
```

I would image something like this but with avalondock tabs. not necessarily new window but just to show the existing window when a button is pressed

Comment: I would assume `wpf`?

Comment: yeah wpf. i know how to do this without avalondock, but with avalondock if i set x:name for example for one window i cant use it in another view for .show method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example shows how to cycle through all document tabs of the custom `DocumentManager` when a *Ctrl + Right* key combination is pressed (in this example the `DocumentManager` control is required to have focus):

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Grid>

    <!-- 
      Border to capture keyboard events of the DocumentManager UserControl. 
      To capture keys in a different scope i.e. more globally, 
      move the input bindings to a parent control.
    -->
    <Border>
      <!-- Bind keyboard keys to a ICommand. -->
      <Border.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Right" 
                    Modifiers="Control" 
                    Command="{Binding NavigateToNextDocument}"/>
      </Border.InputBindings>

      <DocumentManager x:Name="DocumentManager" />
    </Border>
  </Grid
</Window>
```

**DocumentManager.xaml**

```
<UserControl>    
  <Grid>
    <xceed:DockingManager DocumentsSource="{Binding DocumentMainPool}">

      <xceed:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Document}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </xceed:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>

      <xceed:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="xcad:LayoutItem">
          <Setter Property="Title"
                  Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />
          <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                  Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />

          <!-- Important -->
          <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                  Value="{Binding Model.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
      </xceed:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>

      <xceed:LayoutRoot>
        <xceed:LayoutPanel>
          <xceed:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>

            <!-- *** Dynamically created content (by view model) *** -->
            <xceed:LayoutDocumentPane />

          </xceed:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
        </xceed:LayoutPanel>
      </xceed:LayoutRoot>
    </xceed:DockingManager>

  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyProeprtyChanged
{
  public MainViewModel()
  {
    this.DocumentMainPool = new ObservableCollection<IDocument>() 
    {
      new Document("First Document"), 
      new Document("Second Document")
    };
  }

  private ObservableCollection<IDocument> documentMainPool;
  public ObservableCollection<IDocument> DocumentMainPool
  {
    get => this.documentMainPool;
    set
    {
      this.documentMainPool = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public ICommand NavigateToNextDocument => new RelayCommand(param => CycleNextDocuments());

  private void CycleNextDocuments()
  {
    // Only one or no document -> nothing to cycle through
    if (this.DocumentMainPool.Count < 2)
    {
      return;
    }

    IDocument currentlySelectedDocument = this.DocumentMainPool.FirstOrDefault(document => document.IsSelected);
    int currentDocumentIndex = this.DocumentMainPool.IndexOf(currentlySelectedDocument);

    // If last document reached, show first again
    if (currentDocumentIndex == this.DocumentMainPool.Count - 1)
    {
      this.DocumentMainPool.FirstOrDefault().IsSelected = true;
      return;
    }

    IDocument nextDocument = this.DocumentMainPool
      .Skip(currentDocumentIndex + 1)
      .Take(1)
      .FirstOrDefault();
    nextDocument.IsSelected = true;
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**IDocument.cs**

```
// Important: IsSelected must raise PropertyChanged
public interface IDocument : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  string Title { get; set; }
  bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

**Document.cs**

```
public class Document : IDocument
{
  public Document(string title)
  {
    this.Title = title;
  }

  #region Implementation of IDocument

  public string Title { get; set; }

  private bool isSelected;
  public bool IsSelected
  {
    get => this.isSelected;
    set
    {
      this.isSelected = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  #endregion
}
```

**RelayCommand.cs**
Implementation taken from *[Microsoft Docs: Patterns - WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic)*:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields 
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    #endregion // Fields 
    #region Constructors 
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _execute = execute; _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    #endregion // Constructors 

    #region ICommand Members 
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter) { _execute(parameter); }
    #endregion // ICommand Members 
}
```

Comment: wasnt really what i was looking for but it kinda solves the problem in other way arround. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [solution that works with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61572687/avalondock-dockingmanager-activecontent-does-not-update) which makes sense since it is an MVVM framework :-) (have not tried it myself, yet, but the code looks sane).